# Finding the recursive definition of following:

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am struggling with finding a recursive definition of the following:

$$a_0 = 1$$
$$a_1 = -(nx-1)$$
$$a_2 = (n+1)*x*(nx-2)+1$$
$$a_3 = -((n+2)*x*((n+1)*x*(nx-3)+3)-1)$$
$$a_4 = ((n+3)*x*((n+2)*x*((n+1)*x*(nx-4)+6)-4)+1)$$
...

There is a certain pattern for sure, however I'm not able to convert it into a recursive definition.

Comment: Can you show your ideas and approches?